# When using the function By in R, how do I create a vector of the factors for each group?

Tags: r, subset, tapply

I am using the function "by" in R and at the end, I would like a vector with the factors in it as well because I want to create a data frame that has what I computed and the factor next to it that the function used to subset that particular group. How do I extract the factors from the output? The setup is as followed.

```
id <- rep(14:18,each=5)
x <- rep(5:9,each =5)
y <- rep(5:9, each = 5)
t <- data.frame(id = id,x=x,y=y)
s <- by(t,id,function(h){ (h$x%*%h$y)/sum(h$y)})
```

In the final output I would like something like this.

```
sum id 
 5  14
 6  15
 7  16
 8  17
 9  18
```

Thanks

Comment: Your attempted output of a matrix multiplication, `%*%`, does not align with expected output which can be done with `aggregate()`. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry about that.I have updated the code. It was suppose to divide by the sum of one of the columns which I left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider returning a data frame within your `by` call and not single-value vector where your calculation is rendered as a new column and *x* and *y* columns are removed all using `transform()`, the function to manipulate columns and then return adjusted data frame.

Then, to avoid duplicate data (since you are running an aggregation), wrap result in `unique()`. Finally, since `by` will return a list of one-row data frames, run a `do.call(rbind, ...)` outside to row bind all elements together.

```
df_list <- by(t,id, function(sub)
                        unique(transform(sub, 
                                         sum_output = (x %*% y) / sum(y), 
                                         x = NULL, 
                                         y = NULL)
                        )
           )

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
row.names(final_df) <- NULL

final_df 

#   id sum
# 1 14   5
# 2 15   6
# 3 16   7
# 4 17   8
# 5 18   9
```